# CSS sprite duplicate and overlap when class changed

Tags: css, sprite

I have a simple navigation with 'back', 'play/stop' and 'forth' buttons made via sprite. Here is the CSS for navigation

```
.threesixty-nav-bar a {
    background: url(../images/icons/32/1_holly_green.png) no-repeat;
}
```

CSS for 'play' button:

```
.threesixty-nav-bar .threesixty-play {
    background-position: -160px 0;
}
```

CSS for 'stop' button:

```
.threesixty-nav-bar .threesixty-stop {
    background-position: -160px -32px;
}
```

When user clicks on play button, class changed and image position is changed. But the problem is that old position remain and two buttons overlap. It seems like it has both classes same time, but it's not.

However it's happening only on [this](http://www.atreum.net/?page_id=6872) site, click on Shimano bike and wait while it's loading.

On all other sites it's working just fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on this site is that you have two ".threesixty-nav-bar" elements where one is on top of another. So, when you change the background of the one on top, you could still see the bottom one under it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! Don't understand why I didn't see this, now it looks so obvious:) Now I need to understand why there is duplicate navigation;)